# How to access a specific field in Expressjs returned by mongodb collection.find method?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I'm Trying to access one field returned from mongodb collection.find method
, I can't do that and nothing is showing on the console.log

```
router.get('/buildings', function(req, res, next) {
var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('buildings');

collection.find({buildingNO:"1"},{},function(e,docs){
     var x=docs[0].price;
     console.log(x);
    });
});
```

Note: I'm using monk middle-ware not native mongodb

thanks

Comment: If you console `docs` what do you get

Comment: You have a typo on doc[0] you should use docs[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the error argument in the callback and your return argument is:

```
x=docs[0]...
```

And not:

```
x=doc[0]
```

I'm surprised you don't get an undefined variable error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use The **feature** `projection` in nodejs .

The projection is the second object you pass empty `{}` so will project all attributes.

For example :

If you project an object like:

```
{
_id:false// or 0
}
```

Will omit the `_id` attribute.

Here we will pass `price`:

```
collection.find({buildingNO:"1"},{price:1},function(e,docs){
     var x=docs[0].price;
     console.log(x);
    });
```

> You have a **typo** on **doc[0]** should be **docs**

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/